# generate or extract a automatic thumbnail for a video file using Video module in drupal 7

Tags: nodes, files

I need to show a video thumbnail of a video file which the admin upload using the video module.

I have a content type called MEDIA.I have created field as with following settings.

```
   LABEL             NAME           FIELD   WIDGET           OPERATIONS

   Upload Videos    field_video Video   Video Upload    edit    delete
```

Here The following setting I have set for the Upload videos label

```
         UPLOAD VIDEOS FIELD SETTINGS
```

These settings apply to the Upload Videos field everywhere it is used.

```
    Number of values: 1


   Upload destination
   Public files:checked

Enable auto video conversion:checked
 Convert videos automatically using FFmpeg or Zencoder. You can define presets at preset        settings to automatically convert videos to web compatible formats eg. FLV, MP4. Make sure   to configure your transcoder settings to make this work properly.
Video thumbnails
Automatically extract thumbnails from video (with fallback to manual upload):checked

  If you choose Automatically extract thumbnails from video then please make sure to      configure your transcoder settings to make this work properly.
```

Here I have checked the Automatically extract thumbnails from video  check box and I have saved it.

I have configure the transcoder  setting as follows.(I am working on windows XP)

```
  Video transcoder
    FFmpeg:checked
  Select a video transcoder will help you convert videos and generate thumbnails.

    Zencoder is unavailable: The Zencoder API module has not been setup properly.
   PATH TO FFMPEG EXECUTABLE
    FFMPEG:C:/xampp/htdocs/newsite/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg

   Absolute path to FFmpeg executable.When you install a new FFmpeg version, please clear the caches to let Drupal detect the updated codec support.
   VIDEO THUMBNAILS
    Path to save thumbnails:videos/thumbnails

    Path to save video thumbnails extracted from videos.
    Number of thumbnails:5

    Number of thumbnails to extract from video.
    Save all thumbnails in {file_managed} table
    Save all auto-created thumbnails to the {file_managed} table. Change file status as PERMANENT
```

Then I created a new media article where i upload the video from my system and But what happens the video thumbnail is not extracting from the video which I upload.

Can anyone help me.Please forgive me for my english

Answer (score -1):

Are there any messages in your Drupal error log related to video transcoding? Also, try to update to the latest version of the Video module.

Comment: That's a comment not an answer.